# Hibernate retrieve wrong list of objects in one-to-many relation

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I'm new to hibernate. I have to tables Department and Teacher. One Department can have many teachers, but one teacher can be attached to only one department. I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "fName")
    private String fName;

    @Column(name = "lName")
    private String sName;

    @Column(name = "degree")
    private String degree;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
}
```

also there are getters and setters, which I omitted for simplicity. 
I'm using MySql database. When I trying to insert new department with new teachers, everything works fine. But, also I want be able to get a full list of departments with teachers, assigned to each department. Currently in my database i have 5 departments and 13
teachers. But when I executing following code:

```
    DepartmentDaoImpl ddi = new DepartmentDaoImpl();
    List<Department> departments = ddi.getAllDepartment();

    for (Department k : departments){
        printDepartmentData(k);
        List<Teacher> teachers = k.getTeachers();
        for (Teacher t : teachers){
            printTeacherName(t);
        }
    }
```

And my getAllDepartments implementation:

```
@Override
public ArrayList getAllDepartment() throws SQLException {
    Session session = null;
    ArrayList<Department> result = null;
    try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        result = (ArrayList)session.createCriteria(Department.class).list();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(session != null && session.isOpen()){
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Sql to create tables:

```
CREATE TABLE teacher (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
fName varchar(30),
lName VARCHAR(30),
degree VARCHAR(100),
department_id INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE department(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(100),
description VARCHAR(5000) 
);
```

I get 13 instances of department. And I get 5 instances of first department (I have 5 teachers assigned to it) each of them have same five teacher assigned, two instances of second department (I have two teachers assigned to it) each of them have two same teachers assigned and so on.
Can someone figure out, how to fix it? I need to get 5 instances of department, with
corresponding number of teachers.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `DepartmentDaoImpl.getAllDepartment()`?

Comment: try to remove the `@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")` and re run, what happen then?

Comment: @mthmulders  Added to the post

Comment: @Angga  then I get empty list of teachers, but only five instances of department

Comment: look to my answer then, your problem is you refer the department_id as FK inside department itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you configure the one to many relationship with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, hibernate performs a join on the two tables. The result you see is caused by this join.

Make sure that you have correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in both `Department` and `Teacher`. If this does not solve the problem, try to use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Converting to Set helps. But is it correct way for hibernate?  For me this approach seems as some workaround.

Comment: No it is the correct approach. If you check Hibernate tutorials you will see that they use the `Set` approach too

Answer (score 0):

Do the below change and test it

```
   @OneToMany (cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="department")
    private List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<Teacher>();
```

Comment: If I understand correct, I should remove JoinColumn annotation? If so, I get the same result.

Comment: And you have to add mappedBy="department"

Comment: can you post your getTeachers() and getDepartment() methods

Comment: I have getTeacherById(int id), getAllTeachers() which return all teachers in table, and same for Department. which of them to post?

Comment: No in Teacher class you need to have a getter and setter method for private Department department and likewise in the Department  class you need to have getter and setter for private List<Teacher> teachers

Answer (score 0):

try change to this :

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy="department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Teacher> teachers = new HashSet<Teacher>();
```

and change that:

```
@ManyToOne
private Department department;
```

to :

```
@Collumn(name = "department")
private Integer department;
```

Comment: If set JoinColumn to "id" as you say, I will get only one teacher in each department. And this teacher add to department by id (which is primary key) in teacher table. I added my SQL to post, may be it will be more clear.

Comment: sorry my bad, i mislead about mappedBy and JoinColumn. fixed now, that work form me, but i test it without fetch and no many to one in the teacher entity

Comment: edited, give example of department anotation inside the teacher

Answer (score 0):

just try this in your dao, it will help

result = (ArrayList) session.createCriteria (Department.class). setResultTransformer (Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();